# Is there an event that fires when the query string changes (Javascript/AngularJS)?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I know that $locationChangeSuccess fires when the URL changes but I want to sense any change in the query string part of a URL.

I'm using ui-router. I'm trying to figure out a way to call a function inside a controller (which is a controller of a view of a state) only when the query string changes. The query string will be changed from a $state.go statement as follows:

```
            $state.go('search', {quotaId: params.quotaId, campaignName: params.campaignName}, {notify:false} ); //update URL query string using input components' data
```